# Images are not being displayed in wordpress

Tags: images

I am trying to upload a .webp image and the image is not rendering in wordpress. I can see the element in the code but it is not rendering in the site.

Comment: If you try and open the image URL what do you get? A 404 error? You can also see these in your browser's debug tools on the Network tab, and probably the console too. Do you see the file on disk in the right place? If so, is your .htaccess or equivalent NGINX config set up correctly, to serve files from disk before going into WordPress routing?

Comment: Go to Tools->Site Health, then under Site Health Info, check to see if WebP is listed as one of the **GD supported file formats** under Media Handling. If not, you will need to check with your hosting support to get this resolved.